# Input to allow for only one decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to format a number upon input, where you can only insert valid numbers. I have everything working except for the decimal. The input box allows me it insert as many decimals as I would like, but I would only like to allow for one (see the last `replace()`).

```
element.oninput = e => {
    let value = e.currentTarget.value;
    let result = value
        // Remove anything that isn't valid in a number
        .replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, '')
        // Remove all dashes unless it is the first character
        .replace(/(?!^)-/g, '')
        // Remove all periods unless it is the last one
        .replace(/(?!)\./g, '');
    element.value = result;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c4f1L3kv/1/

Here are some valid inputs:

```
123.123
-123.12
123
-123
.123
-.123
```

Here are some invalid inputs:

```
123-123
1-2-3
123.123.123
123-123..12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to match a period character if it is followed by another period character, then you can use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like in the expression below:

```
/\.(?=.*\.)/g
```

Explanation:

- `\.` - Match a literal `.` character
- `(?=` - Start of a positive lookahead

  - `.*\.` - Match zero or more characters until a literal `.` character.
- `)` - Close of the positive lookahead

```js
var element = document.querySelector('input');
element.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  event.target.value = event.target.value
    // Remove anything that isn't valid in a number
    .replace(/[^\d-.]/g, '')
    // Remove all dashes unless it is the first character
    .replace(/(?!^)-/g, '')
    // Remove all periods unless it is the last one
    .replace(/\.(?=.*\.)/g, '');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

---

Based on your comment below:

If you would like to prevent the user from adding a period character at the end of the string if a period character is already present, then you could use the expression `/(\..*)\.$/` and replace the first capturing group with itself, which will effectively remove whatever wasn't in the capturing group (i.e., the last period character).

```js
var element = document.querySelector('input');
element.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  event.target.value = event.target.value
    // Remove anything that isn't valid in a number
    .replace(/[^\d-.]/g, '')
    // Remove all dashes unless it is the first character
    .replace(/(?!^)-/g, '')
    // Remove the last period if there is already one
    .replace(/(\..*)\.$/, '$1')
    // Remove all periods unless it is the last one
    .replace(/\.(?=.*\.)/g, '');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: I like this, but is it possible to instead of removing the previous period to disable the insertion of another period?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I think Josh handle the pasting too. If you prevent the user from just inserting a new one then he can by-pass it by pasting a wrong number.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var element = document.querySelector('input');


element.oninput = e => {
    let value = e.currentTarget.value;
    let result = value
        .replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, '')
        .replace(/(?!^)-/g, '')
        // prevent inserting dots after the first one
        .replace(/([^.]*\.[^.]*)\./g, '$1');
    element.value = result;
}
```

```html
<input/>
```

Comment: Cool! could you update the answer with an explanation of the regexp?

Comment: There is a slight problem with this since all the `.` characters in input strings like `.1.2.3.4.5...6789` aren't removed (if you paste the string into the field).

Comment: @JoshCrozier you mean if the user pastes it??

Comment: Another thing, I don't think removing a starting dot is valid either. since `.123` is a valid number.